# Wordpress: posts/pages that displays content of a single comment?

Tags: wordpress, comments, permalinks, posts

I need to somehow make single posts/pages for comments. So i can show the comments as separate pages with there own permalinks. So that users can access theese pages in browser with the comment page permalink.

Thankful for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress: show comment on a new page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414370/wordpress-show-comment-on-a-new-page)

Comment: I think you can delete this question yourself, so we don't have too many duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I had previously posted an answer over on WordPress Answers (also a StackExchange site) [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/277/showing-comments-on-a-page-without-parent-post/281#281).